# spherically symmetric rearrangement $x^{p}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I need to prove that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} {(f^*)}^p = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} {f}^p
$$
there $f^*$ denotes the **spherically symmetric rearrangement** of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follows from $\mu(\{ \eta : |f(\eta)|>r\})=\mu(\{ \eta  :  f^*(\eta)>r\})$